# Query to match products to customers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, matching

We have a wide variety of products, with many added each day.

Customers can sign up for an email alert. These is sent in bulk each evening, with customers receiving a bespoke list of products that match what they are looking for.

There are three relevant tables in the database:

- Accounts (pk_AccountID,EmailAddress,Title,Name)
- Accounts_Alerts (fk_AccountID,pk_AlertID,Category,MaxPrice,Colour)
- Products (pk_ItemID,Category,Title,Price,Colour,DateModified)

What is the most efficient way to select the latest 10 products added during the last 24 hours that match the options each customer has selected?

This is what I have so far, which works, but it doesn't select only the top 10 products by date (i.e. the latest added). We don't want to send a customer 30+ products to look through in an email.

```
SELECT
   a.pk_AccountID,
   aa.pk_AlertID,
   a.Title As Title,
   a.Name As Name,       
   a.EmailAddress As EmailAddress,
   p.pk_ItemID As ItemID,
   p.Category As Category,
   p.Title As Title,
   p.Price As Price,
   p.Colour As Colour

   FROM dbo.Accounts_Alerts aa
   INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts a ON aa.fk_AccountID=a.pk_AccountID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products p ON 
   (aa.Category = p.Category OR aa.Category IS NULL)
   AND (aa.Colour = p.Colour OR aa.Colour IS NULL)       
   AND (aa.MaxPrice >= p.Price OR aa.MaxPrice IS NULL)
   AND getdate()-1 < p.DateModified

   WHERE
   a.EmailAddress is not null AND
   a.pk_AccountID = @AccountIDVariable
   ORDER BY aa.pk_AlertID
```

Comment: You can use `top 10` to get 10 rows.

Comment: If you need top 10 products per user, you can add row_number() or rank() to your query, partition by user and limit it to be <= 10. You'll need to wrap your SQL inside another select for that.

Comment: The windowed function [row number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is great for this.  Use partition by, to return 10 rows per customer.  If you add an [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) I'm sure someone will help you rewrite your query.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to handle this is with **windowing functions** and an **inline view**, which SQL Server handles quite well.

For example:

```
SELECT
   pk_AccountID,
   pk_AlertID,
   Title,
   Name,       
   EmailAddress,
   ItemID,
   Category,
   Title,
   Price,
   Colour
FROM (
    SELECT
       a.pk_AccountID,
       aa.pk_AlertID,
       a.Title As Title,
       a.Name As Name,       
       a.EmailAddress As EmailAddress,
       p.pk_ItemID As ItemID,
       p.Category As Category,
       p.Title As Title,
       p.Price As Price,
       p.Colour As Colour,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (
            partition by a.pk_AccountID, p.pk_ItemID 
            order by p.DateModified desc
       ) as rseq
    FROM dbo.Accounts_Alerts aa
    INNER JOIN dbo.Accounts a ON aa.fk_AccountID=a.pk_AccountID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products p ON 
        (aa.Category = p.Category OR aa.Category IS NULL)
        AND (aa.Colour = p.Colour OR aa.Colour IS NULL)       
        AND (aa.MaxPrice >= p.Price OR aa.MaxPrice IS NULL)
        AND getdate()-1 < p.DateModified
    WHERE
        a.EmailAddress is not null AND
        a.pk_AccountID = @AccountIDVariable
) as any_alias_will_do
where rseq <= 10
ORDER BY pk_AlertID
```

Notice the `ROW_NUMBER()` function - you will need to make sure that you are "partitioning by" and "ordering by" the correct criteria (I chose Account ID and Item ID here, but you may need different fields).  Try running just the inner query by itself to help you understand how this works.

This technique is quite versatile - recommend you to read up on these functions further.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Unfortunately, having edited your code to add further fields I need and tested it, it consistently takes a long long time (1 minute+) and sometimes gives out of memory errors. Would it be faster to select the products from the last 24 hours into a temporary table and select from that for each alert?

Comment: I tried it with a temporary table and made it worse. 4 minutes rolled by and then out of memory. I then rolled it back to using the product table directly and it's now out of memory every time.

Comment: @TVRV8S First, I believe you what you're saying and I can't solve it without more insight but I have some suggestions for you. Second, this query style is ubiquitous and well-supported, so it should NOT *HAVE* to be slow!!! Third, to optimize whatever is causing problems, you need to be familiar with the indexes defined on the tables, as well as the *execution plans* for the queries - the execution plans should tell you what is using the most resources and lead you toward a solution.  Of course, you can ignore this technique altogether, but I use it enough myself to want to save it for you :)